# Explicit example of a certain weak-* limit

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem set up:**

Consider $C_b$, the Banach space of continuous bounded functions on $[0, \infty)$ equipped with the sup norm. Denote by $M$ the set of probability measures on $[0, \infty)$, and for $r > 0$ denote by $M_r$ the set of probability measures supported on $[r, \infty)$. We will consider $M$ as subsets of the continuous dual $C_b^*$ in the usual way.

Consider the set $\mathcal S$ of linear functionals $L \in C_b^*$ such that there exist a sequence $r_n$ of real numbers with $r_n \to \infty$, and a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ with $\mu_n \in M_{r_n}$ for all $n$ such that $\mu_n \to L$ in the weak* topology.

By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, $\mathcal S$ is nonempty.

> **Question:** Is it possible to produce an explicit example of an element of $\mathcal S$, and the corresponding probability measures?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Edited.

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense: every probability measure on $[0,\infty)$ induces a member of $C_b^*$, but the converse is very far from being true.  So $\mathcal S$ need not actually contain any functional induced by a probability measure.

Comment: Also, as $C_b$ is non-separable, I am not completely sure (but I could be wrong) whether you really can get the _sequence_ $(\mu_n)$ to converge, or whether you will need to look as a _sub-net_ of $(\mu_n)$, equivalently, as limit-point of $(\mu_n)$.

Comment: I didn’t specify that the element of $\mathcal S$ needed to be induced by a probability measure though.

Comment: Also I believe $C^0 (X)$ is separable for $X$ separable.

Comment: Ah, okay, I guess I misread "...and the corresponding probability measures".  But where in the question does $C^0(X)$ occur?

Comment: Ah, so I use $C^0$ to mean the set of continuous functions. $C_b$ being an open subset of $C^0$ should then be separable a well.

Comment: @NateRiver that's not the usual use of $C^0$, which is usually the bounded functions that vanish at infinity. Now those are usually denoted $C_0(X)$, which is indeed separable when $X$ is separable. However, the $C_b$ in your question is non-separable, as it contains $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the set of probability measures on a separable metric space is *sequentially* closed in the weak* topology of $C_b^{\ast}$, so $\mathcal{S}$ would be empty, if you didn't allow nets. I don't have a reference, though, so take it with a grain a salt.

Comment: @Diego Martinez ah you’re right - I had the result mixed up.

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski That is correct, the space of measures on the real line is w* sequentially complete; see e.g. Bogachev, Measure Theory (2007), section 8.7. So the set $\cal S$ as defined in the question is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(reading "sequence" as "net", as suggested in the comments)

Well, $C_b(\mathbb{R}^+) \cong C(\beta\mathbb{R}^+)$, so any such $L$ will arise from a probability measure on the Stone-Cech remainder $\beta\mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \mathbb{R}^+$. You need some choice principle to know this set is nonempty, so no example can be very explicit. (I think it's consistent with ZF that there are no free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{R}^+$.)

If you're willing to take ultrafilters as "explicit", then evaluation on a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ would be an example.